# Apache Poi Ignoring Autogenerated Formulas

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am attempting to use poi to read through an excel file and copy it to a separate file. I have this functioning correctly however for auto generated formulas in excel using the drag down tool (See image) [Drag down tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SGvK.png)
The date "00/01/1900" appears as a string in the cells instead. Poi is aware that the cell is a formula however the formula is seen as blank. I believe that the formulas may not be cached as when I click to edit the field in excel and then run my program the formula is displayed correctly.
**The Program:**
 Uses streaming reader found here https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader to read through all cells (As file is too big to use xssf reader and sxssf is too complicated for me)

```
 switch (c.getCellType()) 
                {
                case STRING:
                    cell.setCellValue(c.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case NUMERIC:
                    cell.setCellValue(c.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;
                case BLANK:
                    break;
                case BOOLEAN:
                    cell.setCellValue(c.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                case ERROR:
                    cell.setCellErrorValue(c.getErrorCellValue());
                    break;
                case FORMULA:
                    cell.setCellFormula(c.getCellFormula());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
```

This is used to set new cell value which is added to a workbook and then saved as a file.
Any advice on what I can do about this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you temporarily increase your memory and use regular Apache POI, does it work? It might be a bug in the streaming reader not properly handling shared formulas

Comment: It would appear that I am not the first person to experience this issue: https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader/issues/200 But if anyone has any easy solutions (other than using sxssf) that would be greatly appreciated